# How to hasten Layout inflation after ACTION_SCREEN_ON intent is received?

Tags: java, android, layout, lockscreen

So I've been developing a lockscreen app for Android and I've got most of it to work and it's pretty responsive. The problem I'm facing now is whenever I close an app and lock the phone and unlock it the very next moment, the Lockscreen activity shows up very late or not at all.

I've used different lockscreen apps to check this lag out and AcDisplay faces the same problem.
Although Next Lockscreen(by Microsoft) does not. As far as I have ascertained, it deliberately delays the screen wake up until the Lockscreen Activity has been inflated.

So, it would be very helpful if someone can tell how do I remove this lag or delay the screen wake up like Next does.

**EDIT:**

I've tried using the android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" on the LockscreenActivity

LockscreenActivity.java

```
package com.bikimax.lockscreen;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.support.v4.*;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.bikimax.lockscreen.util.DigitalClock;
import com.bikimax.lockscreen.util.TimeMap;

public class LockscreenActivity extends Activity{


Drawable wallpaper;
Calendar cal;
ImageView background;

WindowManager winManager;
RelativeLayout layout;
View aView;
Button button;
private static Handler handler;
Vibrator vibra;
boolean bWallpaperEnabled;
boolean btextClockEnabled;
SharedPreferences SP;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Daze", "Lockscreen Activity Created");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_lockscreen);


    SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

    boolean bWallpaperEnabled = SP.getBoolean("wallpaperEnable",false);

     WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams( WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE|
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH|
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE| 
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION|
             View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
     winManager = ((WindowManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
     layout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());
     getWindow().setAttributes(localLayoutParams);


     View.inflate(this, R.layout.activity_lockscreen, this.layout);
     this.winManager.addView(layout, localLayoutParams); 
    // mDetector = new GestureDetector(this,this);



    // myThread = null;
    // Thread myThread = null;
    // Runnable myRunnableThread = new CountDownRunner();
    // myThread = new Thread(myRunnableThread);
    // myThread.start();



     //Fonts
     final Typeface OpenSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Light.ttf"); // size: 27dp
     final Typeface Alcubierre = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Alcubierre.otf"); // numeral size: 40dp 

     getApplicationContext();
    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     TelephonyMgr.listen(new TeleListener(),PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); 

    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setTypeface(OpenSans);
    background = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    if(bWallpaperEnabled == true){
       background.setBackground(myWallpaperManager.getDrawable());
       background.getBackground().setColorFilter(0x7f000000, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
    }



   handler = new Handler();

   Runnable updateCurrentTime = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            btextClockEnabled = SP.getBoolean("textClockEnable",false);

            cal = Calendar.getInstance();

            String digitalClock = DigitalClock.createTimeString(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
            String textClock = TimeMap.createTimeString(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));


            if(btextClockEnabled == true){
                button.setTypeface(OpenSans);
                button.setText(textClock);

            }

            else{
                button.setTextSize(40);
                button.setTypeface(Alcubierre);
                button.setText(digitalClock);
            } // Update the current Time
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000);  // Run this again in 1 second
            // (i.e. we create an infinite loop that
            // executes every second)
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(updateCurrentTime,1); // The first call to the
    // updateCurrentTime Runnable with
    // a 5 second delay   

   Log.i("Daze","Lockscreen Activity Set Up");

}

  public void unlock(){

      finish();
      System.exit(0);


  }

  public void onUnlock(View view){
        Log.i("Daze", "Unlock Button Pressed");
        vibra =  (Vibrator) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibra.vibrate(350);
        unlock();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        winManager.removeView(this.layout);
        layout.removeAllViews();

        super.onDestroy();
        //myThread.interrupt();
        Log.i("Daze","Lockscreen Activity Destroyed");
    }

    /*
    public void doWork(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                try{

                    //Fonts
                    Typeface OpenSans = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/OpenSans/OpenSans-Light.ttf"); // size: 27dp
                    Typeface Alcubierre = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Alcubierre.otf"); // numeral size: 40dp 
                    SP = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
                    btextClockEnabled = SP.getBoolean("textClockEnable",false);

                    cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                    String digitalClock = DigitalClock.createTimeString(cal.get(cal.MINUTE), cal.get(cal.HOUR));
                    String textClock = TimeMap.createTimeString(cal.get(cal.MINUTE),cal.get(cal.HOUR_OF_DAY));


                    if(btextClockEnabled == true){
                        button.setTypeface(OpenSans);
                        button.setText(textClock);

                    }

                    else{
                        button.setTextSize(40);
                        button.setTypeface(Alcubierre);
                        button.setText(digitalClock);
                    }




                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        });
    }




    private class CountDownRunner implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run(){
            while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                try {
                    doWork();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                catch(Exception e){

                }
            }
        }
    }

    */


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lockscreen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

class TeleListener extends PhoneStateListener {
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
       super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
       switch (state) {
       case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
        unlock();
        break;
       default:
        break;
       }
      }

     }
```

}

LockscreenReceiver.java

```
package com.bikimax.lockscreen;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class LockscreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public LockscreenReceiver() {

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent0) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    Intent intent = new Intent(context,LockscreenActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    Log.i("Daze", "Lockscreen activated");
}
```

}

Comment: Add Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @user861594 I've edited it.